# How to handle trailing slash in a redirect rule for an AWS S3 website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to build up some landing pages in my s3 hosted web site.

For example: `http://www.example.com/products`

That should redirect to `http://www.example.com/products.html`

To accomplish this, I learned about redirect rules and I created this working rule:

**website.json**

```
{
    "Bucket": "www.example.com",
    "WebsiteConfiguration": {
        "ErrorDocument": {
            "Key": "404.html"
        },
        "IndexDocument": {
            "Suffix": "index.html"
        },
        "RoutingRules": [
            {
                "Condition": {
                    "KeyPrefixEquals": "products/"
                },
                "Redirect": {
                    "ReplaceKeyWith": "products.html"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I uploaded this json file using the command line: `aws s3api put-bucket-website --cli-input-json file://website.json`

**Problem:**

**The trailing slash.**  For this to function, the user must navigate to http://www.example.com/products/  I would like the user to be able to navigate to http://www.example.com/products <-- no trailing slash.

I've tried to remove it from the rule.  It messes up. This appears to be impossible.  Is it?

Related Posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48741715/control-s3-bucket-hosted-websites-trailing-slash-redirects